# Grails Enum Mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm

in Grails, Is there a way to limit the size of the column to which the enum is mapped. In the following example, i would like the column type to be char(2)

```
enum FooStatus {
    BAR('br'), TAR('tr')
    final static String id
}

class Foo {
    FooStatus status

    static constraints = {
        status(inList:FooStatus.values()*.id,size:2..2)
    }
}
```

both inList and size do not have any effect when exporting the schema, the column type keeps its default value (varch(255))
Maybe i could do that if i define a new UserType. Any idea ?

Thank you
-ken

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think it's directly possible given the way enums are mapped internally in GORM. But changing the code to this works:

```
enum FooStatus {
   BAR('br'),
   TAR('tr')
   private FooStatus(String id) { this.id = id }
   final String id

   static FooStatus byId(String id) {
      values().find { it.id == id }
   }
}
```

and

```
class Foo {
   String status

   FooStatus getFooStatus() { status ? FooStatus.byId(status) : null }
   void setFooStatus(FooStatus fooStatus) { status = fooStatus.id }

   static transients = ['fooStatus']

   static constraints = {
      status inList: FooStatus.values()*.id
   }

   static mapping = {
      status sqlType: 'char(2)'
   }
}
```

Adding the transient getter and setter allows you to set or get either the String (id) or enum value.

Comment: It's quite annoying that i have to add for every enum type a getter and a setter and also declare it as "transient". Burt, wouldn't a custom UserType be a more elegant solution ?

Comment: The transient and getter/setter are optional if you're ok with setting the Enum's id and converting the id to the enum instance in the calling code. The real change is persisting a String instead of the Enum (which was sort of implied by your use of inList() since that wouldn't work with the Enum anyway). But sure, a custom UserType should work. You'd want to extract common stuff into a base class if you do this more than once. My preference would be to keep everything in the domain class if possible, as long as the changes aren't that significant.

Comment: Burt, yes you're right i want to be able to set and get the status variable as an enum and also be able to save the database thus the use of the id in the enum. I'm leaning more toward a custom user type something along mapping= {status type:EnumUserType }

Comment: Burt, Do you know if there is a bug in JIRA on this one?  You ought to be able to give an Enum a sqlType in the mapping block.

Answer (score 11):

Grails ships with an undocumented (as far as I can tell anyway) custom Hibernate mapping for enums. The class is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.IdentityEnumType. It won't let you set the column size but does make it easy to change what is stored in the DB for each enum value without having to add transient fields to your model.

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.IdentityEnumType

class MyDomainClass {
    Status status

    static mapping = {
        status(type: IdentityEnumType)
    }

    enum Status {
        FOO("F"), BAR("B")
        String id
        Status(String id) { this.id = id }
    }
}
```

You can run an 'alter table' in Bootstrap.groovy to shrink the column:

```
DataSource dataSource
...
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
sql.execute("alter table my_domain_class change column status status varchar(1) not null")
```

Comment: which version are you talking about?

Comment: Are you asking about the Grails version? 2.2.1 and others

Answer (score 2):

Even easier (works at least in Grails 2.1.0+)

```
class DomainClass {
    Status status
    static mapping = {
         status(enumType: "string")
    }
}
```

---

```
enum Status {
    OPEN     ("OPEN"),
    CLOSED   ("CLOSED"),
    ...

    String name
    Status (String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since GORM 6.1 identity enum mapping can be enabled with such construct

```
static mapping = {
   myEnum enumType:"identity"
}
```