# Grails - CreateCriteria to Retrieve any entry that contains any element in query

Tags: grails, hql, criteria

Given I have this domain:

```
class Game {
   Set<GameType> gameType
   String name
}
```

And this enum:

```
enum Gametype {
    RHYTHM, ADVENTURE, PUZZLE, RPG, HORROR, FIGHTING, MOBA, MMO
}
```

I need to retrieve a list of games that contains **at least one** of the game types indicated in the query. I tried using this code:

```
def retrieveGamesThatMayBeUnderGameTypes( List<GameType> listOfGameTypes) {
   return Game.createCriteria().list(){
      'in'("gameType", listOfGameTypes)
   }
}
```

However, it returns a NullPointerException. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your enum (`Gametype`) has a field called `id`. Something like:

```
enum Gametype {
    RHYTHM('RHYTHM'),
    ADVENTURE('ADVENTURE'),
    ....

    String id

    Gametype(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

See this answer for more: [Grails Enum Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748760/grails-enum-mapping)

Comment: Does it have to be a field called `id`? Can it be another data type? Can it be another domain or enum?

Comment: It needs to be called `id` - that's the rule otherwise hibernate wouldn't know how to refer the value of the bean to. The `id` column can be of any type, not only `String` though.

Comment: I see. Currently the database does not have a table for the enum though. Would adding id cause the enum to have its own table?

Comment: No, you don't have to have the table in your database but there's nothing stopping you from adding that table. In fact it's a good idea to have this table in your database in case you query the table directly or there's other system using the data.

Comment: It does not throw a NullPointerException, but it returns an empty list now.

Comment: I just realized that my criteria tries to find the `Games` whose `gameTypes` matches **ALL** of what's inside `listOfGameTypes` instead of any of those. I need to return all the games whose gameTypes contain at least one of the listOfGameTypes given by the user.